# SVG animation is hidden before it begins

Tags: animation, svg, svg-animate

http://codepen.io/Asider/pen/mVBONd

Hello world,

I'm learning how to animate SVGs, and I've encountered a problem with `begin="click"` : the element is invisible and thus unclickable.

Is it normal that svg elements are hidden before their animation begin ? How can I make sure it's visible (and thus clickable) ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the element's `d` attribute to a default value, otherwise, it won't render anything :

```css
.test {
  display: block;
  transform: scale(3);
  margin: 0 auto 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="test" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
  <path fill="#00ff00" d="M30.1,29.6V21l-5.3-5.4L19.9,21v3.3h-8.6v15.3h27.3V29.6H30.1z">
    <animate attributeName="d" values="M30.1,29.6V21l-5.3-5.4L19.9,21v3.3h-8.6v15.3h27.3V29.6H30.1z;
                    M30.1,23.6V16l-5.3-5.4L19.9,14v3.3h-8.6v22.3h27.3V23.6H30.1z;
                    M30.1,24.6V16l-5.3-5.4L19.9,16v3.3h-8.6v20.3h27.3V24.6H30.1z;" from="0" to="1" dur="1200ms" fill="freeze" begin="click" keyTimes="0; .8; 1" calcMode="linear" repeatcount="indefinite" />
  </path>
</svg>
```

Comment: That was simple... Thanks Kaiido !